# How to correctly handle ajax timeouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For example, a user want to login, the connection is slow or the request is stuck into some network , then the user waits, but sometimes is better resend the request than waiting.

Questions:

- What would be the desirable waiting time? (no uploading files, just
  simple login) I've put 15 secs, but maybe it's too much.
- What's the best solution?

1) Keep the user waiting till he decides to click login again

2) Set an ajax timeout

```
$.ajax({

url: '{{ url('/login') }}',
data: data,
method: 'POST',
timeout: 15000,
```

and display them an error

```
error: function(data, status, error){

if(status==="timeout") {
var errorString = 'Please retry. Ref Timeout';                      
}
```

3) do an auto retry ([code](https://gist.github.com/aeurielesn/2511005))

```
$.ajax({
url : 'someurl',
type : 'POST',
data :  ....,   
tryCount : 0,
retryLimit : 3,
...
error: function(data, status, error){
    if (status == 'timeout') {
       this.tryCount++;
       if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
       //try again
           $.ajax(this);
           return;
       }            
       return;
    }
```

4) Use a wrapper function over the ajax

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({...})
}, 15000);
```

5) [Some other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024469/whats-the-best-way-to-retry-an-ajax-request-on-failure-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally do a mix, that means, try 2 times and the fall, you can use this code:

```
$.ajax({

    url: '{{ url('/login') }}',
    data: data,
    method: 'POST',
    timeout: 10000, // sets timeout to 5000 = 5 seconds
    retryCount: 0, // start retry count
    retryLimit: 1, //will let you retry a determined number of times

error: function(data, status, error){       

if(status==="timeout") {
    this.retryCount++;
    if (this.retryCount <= this.retryLimit) { //&& Date.now() - this.created <  this.retryTimeout
        console.log("Retrying");
        $.ajax(this);
        return;
}
else{
    var errorString = 'Timeout';                        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Default server timeout is 30s, so it's proper timeout in Ajax.

Don't bombard server with re-logins (if it's too busy, you make it even worse).

Do not allow user to click login button once more while request is pending.

---

*IMO* there should be ajax without timeout and on error you should tell user to try again later.

```
$.ajax({
    error: function (response) {
        console.error(response); // Show error response to dev

        alert('Something went wrong. Please try again later or contact administrator admin@email.com'); // Use pretty modal instead
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could you a library like https://github.com/inmar/patience_js that lets you define retry strategies and keep your code a lot cleaner.

Or better yet take a look at [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/)

where you can use an approach like the one suggested here: [RxJS retry operator with ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073058/rxjs-retry-operator-with-ajax-call)

```
const doLogin = () => {
    console.log('calling');
    return $.ajax('...')
};

const stream = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(doLogin).retry(3);

stream.subscribe(log);
```